# Inverse transparent area in SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this SVG :

```
<svg class="decor" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0 L100 100 L0 100" stroke-width="0"></path>
</svg>
```

This works but I need to have transparent outer and black color inner. In my code this is currently inverse.

How to generate this?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gjdjp642/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the coordinates of your SVG path (`d` attribute) to form a triangle instead of the shape.

The modified `path` (`d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0z"`) works as follow:

- `M0 0` - Moves the pen to 0,0 (top left corner)
- `L 50 100` - Draws a line from 0,0 to 50,100 (which is bottom center point)
- `L 100 0` - Draws a line from 50,100 to 100 0 (which is top right corner)
- `z` - Closes the path by drawing a line from the last point (100,0) to the first point (0,0)

SVG `path` elements by default get a black colored `fill` and hence the triangle gets colored black whereas the outside remains transparent.

```css
* {
  background: #e1e1e1;
}
.decor {
  height: 80px
}
```

```html
<div class="decor">
  <svg class="decor" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0z" stroke-width="0"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

---

**Clip Image using Path:**

If the need is to use the `path` to clip background image into the required shape then it would be better to use `clipPath` element and `clip-path` CSS property like in the below snippet:

```css
* {
  background: #e1e1e1;
}
.decor {
  height: 80px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/80);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipper);
  clip-path: url(#clipper);
}
```

```html
<div class="decor">
  <svg height="0" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clipper" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <path d="M0 0 L.5 1 L1 0z"></path>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Putting all the pieces together, the below code should achieve the output that was provided in the image.

```css
.div-1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
.decor-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/550/500');
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipper);
  clip-path: url(#clipper);
}
.div-2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://kinderhtml.themerex.net/img/bg/texture_2.png');
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipper2);
  clip-path: url(#clipper2);
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">
  <div class="decor-top">
    <svg height="0" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipper" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <path d="M0 0 L.5 .1 L1 0 1,1 0,1z"></path>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="div-2">
    <svg height="0" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipper2" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <path d="M0 0 L.5 .25 L1 0 1,1 0,1z"></path>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

The original `path` (`d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0 L100 100 L0 100"`) worked as follows:

- `M0 0` - Moves the pen to 0,0 (top left corner)
- `L 50 100` - Draws a line from 0,0 to 50,100 (which is bottom center point)
- `L 100 0` - Draws a line from 50,100 to 100 0 (which is top right corner)
- `L 100 100` - Draws a line from 100,0 to 100,100 (which is bottom right corner)
- `L0 100` - Draws a line from 100,100 to 0,100 (which is bottom left corner)

Thus the above `path` ends up a forming a shape which looks like a rectangle with a triangle cut-out at the top.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I show this decor over of my div using `absolute` position. now can i set transparent inner SVG(black color) for show background image ?!

Comment: @NewCod3r: You can set the inner color to transparent but that will no clip the image. Are you looking to clip your background image into a triangle? If yes, I can give another solution based on `clip-path` (SVG) that will help you more.

Comment: Yes, I need to clip my background image into a triangle

Comment: I add top decor !! http://jsfiddle.net/gjdjp642/4/ decor height not work and i cant see top decor

Comment: PLease this img: http://imgur.com/tb0kkhK for top decor i have image texture and blue bacground. can i set image and color background for SVG?!

Comment: Sorry Harry Please see full code here : http://jsfiddle.net/gjdjp642/7/ and my need : http://imgur.com/v5AsgBN

Comment: @NewCod3r: Ok, from your image I can see that you need two clip-paths (one for the top and one for the texture). So you can do like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gjdjp642/8/). I had used some other image for decor-top because I couldn't access your image.

Comment: thanks but i need to separated two div.  in action in need to add texture and green background to svg white area see this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/gjdjp642/10/